# Port forwarding on VirtualBox

Tags: apache, virtual-machine, virtualbox, nat

I have to set up a Virtual Machine on vBox that works as a server for my app. Now, the app sends data to http://x.y.w.z:4567. I run apache server on host and wireshark confirms that the packet is received. Guest is behind NAT and is set up to forward TCPs from any IP port 4567 to port 443 on guest. I tried various versions of setting and not setting IP. Guest also has apache running, but it receives no packets. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the log that your port-forward rule is active. Also that your guest/host firewalls doesn't drop packets.

Comment: Firewall on host has exception for vBox and open port 80 (changed it now) as an outgoing rule. Firewall on guest is turned off. Still nothing. Rule is present in options so I assume it's active.

Comment: You've mentioned port 443(usually SSL), so your URL should be https:// localhost:4567, and please make sure that port-forward rule is applied. In the log should be records like: 00:00:02.951808 NAT: set redirect TCP host port 2322 => guest port 22 @ 10.0.2.15